# Associate an in-app purhcased item to a device

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is it possible to associate an item purchased with Google in-app Billing to a device, or to a couple user/device, instead of a simple user?

I'm trying to understand how to make a user pay for each installation of an app that he has bought: is there any other solution that you can suggest me?

One fast solution that I have in mind is to allow the user to purchase a number of consumable items, each one representing a license for a single device, and register somewhere in the device's files or in the shared preferences if the license has been applied; but this creates a problem if the user should reinstall the device, he would lose his license.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality out of the box. You may use the same "fast solution", but store a license in your backend.